# retrieve and print values after comma separator from single field using join (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, select

I have one problem while retrieveing value from mysql using codeigniter.

I have one table name task and in that there is one field of assigneduserid.

**Table - Task:**

```
id  | title     | assigneduserid
-------------------------------------
1   | Workspace | 23,21
```

**Table - User**

```
id  | title 
-----------------
23  | Ashish
21  | Ritesh
```

In assigneduserid field there are two values in that field that is 23,21.

I want to print both usertitle like this : **Ashish,Ritesh** from usertable using that assigneduserid.

And also i want to set that value in ascending order which are in **assigneduseid**

I am trying to print that record on page using echo like following

**Following is Code Where i am printing:**

```
<?php echo $task_row->usertitle;?>
```

Above code is printing only **Ashish**.

but i would like to print **Ashish,Ritesh**

**following is my model.**

```
function getTask($id, $is_master_admin) 
        {
         $this->db->select('workspace.title as workspacetitle, user.title as usertitle,task.*');
        $this->db->join(WORKSPACE, WORKSPACE . '.id = ' . TASK . '.workspaceid', 'inner');
        $this->db->join(USER, USER . '.id = ' . TASK . '.assigneduserid', 'inner');
        $this->db->from(TASK);
        if (!$is_master_admin) {
            $this->db->where(USER . '.id', $id);
        }
        $this->db->where(TASK . '.tasktypeid', '1');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: i cant normalize my table because it is created by my seniors. so i cant 

thank you

Comment: Then may be it is time to tell them who the senior is ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
function getTask($id, $is_master_admin)
{

$this->db->select('task.*, workspace.title as workspacetitle, GROUP_CONCAT( user.title ) AS usertitle,task.assigneduserid,user.id',FALSE);
$this->db->join(WORKSPACE , WORKSPACE . '.id = ' . TASK . '.workspaceid', 'inner');
$this->db->join(USER,("FIND_IN_SET(USER .id , TASK.assigneduserid)"), 'inner');
$this->db->from(TASK);
$this->db->group_by("task.id");
if (!$is_master_admin)
{

$this->db->where ("FIND_IN_SET($id, task.assigneduserid)");
}
$this->db->where(TASK . '.tasktypeid', '1');
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
return $query->result();
} else {
return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) & [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) functions

Try this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, GROUP_CONCAT(u.title) AS userTitle
FROM Task t 
INNER JOIN User u ON FIND_IN_SET(t.assigneduserid, u.id) 
GROUP BY t.id
```

**EDIT::**

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, GROUP_CONCAT(u.title) AS userTitle
FROM Task t 
INNER JOIN `User` u ON CONCAT(',', t.assigneduserid, ',') LIKE ('%,', u.id, ',%')
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: @Ritesh I had never user codeigniter. I can give you solution only in MySQL format. Sorry for that. You have to try yourself.

Comment: That is why i have taged codeigniter but u edited and remove that tag

Comment: is there any otherway??
because FIND_IN_SET will not work with codeigniter

Comment: @Ritesh Check my updated answer. Try it, that will work

Comment: May be you are right but i cant understand how to implement in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

@Ritesh: follow Saharsh Shah, you can put this query into this command $this->db->query(); or you can follow this link to do what you want http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html