# access values after comma separator from single field of mysql (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have one problem while retrieveing value from mysql using codeigniter.

I have one table name task and in that there is one field of assigneduserid.

**Table - Task:**

```
id  | title         | Title     | assigneduserid
--------------------------------------------------------
1   | Workspace     |PMS        | 23,21
```

**Table - User**

```
id  | title 
-----------------
23  | Ashish
21  | Ritesh
```

In assigneduserid field there are two values in that field that is 23,21.

I want to display task title in both user login.
but it displays only to Ashish login.
how can i solve it??

**Following is my model:-**

```
function getTask($id, $is_master_admin) {
        $this->db->select('task.*, workspace.title as workspacetitle, user.title as usertitle');
        $this->db->join(WORKSPACE, WORKSPACE . '.id = ' . TASK . '.workspaceid', 'inner');
        $this->db->join(USER, USER . '.id = ' . TASK . '.userid', 'inner');
        $this->db->from(TASK);
        $this->db->group_by('task.id');
        if (!$is_master_admin) {
            $this->db->where(USER . '.id', $id);
        }
        $this->db->where(TASK . '.tasktypeid', '1');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can any one please help??

Comment: The best solution is to normalize your database tables by adding an `assigneduser` table

Comment: No i cant, because this is designed by my senior and i don't have rights to do that

suggest me other way please

Comment: first select the ids form that task table and then explode the answer and fire select query on user

Comment: you can make use of FIND_IN_SET() function

Comment: @saurabh2836 can u please give me code

Comment: @Nouphal.M i tried FIND_IN_SET() but it is not working

you can change my code and paste here

Comment: Have you tried to echo query using **$this->db->last_query();** ? Checkout what query your code generates? execute in your DB query tool and try to correct your query manually. That will help you to format it properly in codeigniter

Comment: possible duplicate of [retrieve and print values after comma separator from single field using join (codeigniter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878315/retrieve-and-print-values-after-comma-separator-from-single-field-using-join-co)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTask($id, $is_master_admin) {
 $data= $this->db->group_by('task.id')->get('task')->result();//check what value your getting in data and then use foreach and select the user from the user table 
  foreach($data as $value):
   $array= $this->db->where('id',$value->id)->get('user')->result();      
  endforeach;   
}
```

Comment: depend on the value you are getting on data

Answer (score 0):

Try, Haven't checked it,

```
$tsql =  " SELECT task.*, workspace.title AS workspacetitle, GROUP_CONCAT(user.title ORDER BY id) AS usertitle ".
         " INNER JOIN ". WORKSPACE ." ON ". WORKSPACE .".id = " . TASK . ".workspaceid ".
         " INNER JOIN USER ON FIND_IN_SET(".USER . ".id, ". TASK .".assigneduserid ) > 0  ".
         " FROM ". TASK ;


        if (!$is_master_admin) {
           $tsql .= " WHERE ". USER . ".id =". $id;
        }


   $tsql .= " WHERE ". TASK . ".tasktypeid =1 ";        
   $tsql .= " GROUP BY ". TASK .".id ";
$query = $this->db->query($tsql);
```